# Microsoft Graph | get messages with 'gt' filter acts as 'ge'

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm querying Microsoft Graph for new messages (emails) in user inbox.
I want to only get "new" messages so I use gt filter, passing it the time of my last message I handled.
The url I'm approaching is:
 `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/Users/{my-user-id}/messages?$filter=receivedDateTime gt 2019-12-15T23:49:06Z`

The response I'm getting is a single message with the same `receivedDateTime` as the one I used in my query (with `gt`)
Here's the relevant part of the json response I get from Graph:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('my-user-id')/messages",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"etag-replaced\"",
            "id": "message-id-replaced",
            "createdDateTime": "2019-12-15T23:49:05Z",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2019-12-15T23:49:06Z",
            "changeKey": "change-key-replaced",
            "categories": [],
            "receivedDateTime": "2019-12-15T23:49:06Z",   // that's the weird part.
            "sentDateTime": "2019-12-15T23:49:06Z",
            "hasAttachments": false,.....
```

So, it seems like `gt` (greater than) acts as if it was `ge` (greater than or equals), could that be a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underlying Exchange Server stores the Item with a precision down to the milliseconds (EWS allows you specify the precision you want to see in the datetime returned, there is probably a Graph Prefer Header for this (or should be) but I haven't found it). So its most likely technically correct that this item is greater then the date your querying because of its precision. If you want to look at the actual precision on your messages you can use a MAPI editor like OutlookSpy of MFCMapi. You can then look at the PT_Systime value which are FileTime "8 bytes; a 64-bit integer representing the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601" see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee157583(v=EXCHG.80).aspx

The workarounds are just filter it at the client side, or include the milliseconds in the actual query.(I'd agree this is a usability bug as 99% of people will use seconds in their query)